# Find maximal independent set

Tags: c++, algorithm

What will be the basic naive approach to find maximal independent set of a undirected graph given its adjacency matrix .What will be its complexity ?

Like if we have 3 vertices and matrix is :

0 1 0

1 0 1

0 1 0

Here solution will be 2 as maximal independent set includes {1,3}.

How naive approach can be improved also ?

My approach : Select the node with minimum number of edges and  Eliminate all it's neighbors . From the rest of the nodes, select the node with minimum number of edges and repeat the steps until the whole graph is covered
Is this correct?

Comment: dont put questions on close queue less than one minute after they were asked. Moreover without comments.

Comment: @timrau here no algorithm is described.

Comment: @UmNyobe I didnt get you

Comment: @user3405426 My comment is intended to the first person casting a vote to close your question. Your question format is not adequate, but the vote was too early. You need to show what you have already done, and pinpoint a specific issue regarding your attempt. As of now it seems you want us to do your homework.

Comment: @UmNyobe Actually closing as early as possible is generally preferable. This forces the asker to tend to any problems with the post, otherwise they won't be able to get any answers. There are hopelessly too many comments pointing out problems with posts that go ignored. If a question is closed, there is a reason associated with it, which should give the asker sufficient information to be able to fix their post to have it reopened.

Comment: @Dukeling is he able to vote for reopening his question with one rep? Because otherwise the question can be closed at the time of the edit, and forgotten.

Comment: @UmNyobe i edited to describe my approach in it.Anything else ?

Comment: @UmNyobe As far as I'm aware, an edit after the question's been closed causes it to be put into the Reopen review queue. But, by the way, most of the close votes are voting to close as a duplicate, which (assuming it's a duplicate, or close enough) has all the more reason to be closed quickly, and not be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

Finding a Maximal Independent Set (MIS):

> Parallel MIS algorithms use randomization to gain concurrency (Luby's algorithm for graph coloring).
>
> Initially, each node is in the candidate set `C`. Each node generates a (unique) random number and communicates it to its neighbors.
>
> If a nodes number exceeds that of all its neighbors, it joins set `I`. All of its neighbors are removed from `C`.
>
> This process continues until `C` is empty.
>
> On average, this algorithm converges after `O(log|V|)` such steps.